# why i'm getting exception while giving inputs at local host "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

in this Controller when 'stdin.save(std);' is removed code works finr but when I add this 'stdin.save(std);' line i'm getting 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null' this exception

```
package com.access6.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.access6.dao.StudentInt;
import com.access6.model.Student;
@RestController
public class StudentContrlr {
@Autowired
StudentInt stdin;
Student std;

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home() {
return new ModelAndView("home");
}

@RequestMapping("/addStd")
public ModelAndView addStd(@RequestParam ("id") String id, @RequestParam ("name") String name, 
@RequestParam ("location") String location,ModelMap mp ) {
mp.put("id", id);
mp.put("name", name);
mp.put("location", location);
stdin.save(std);
return new ModelAndView("home");
}
}
```

model: @entity cannot create table in database but connection is working fine

```
package com.access6.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Student {
@Id
int id;
String name;
String location;
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
public String getLocation() {
return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
this.location = location;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", location=" + location + "]";
}
}
```

interface

```
package com.access6.dao;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.access6.model.Student;
public interface StudentInt extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

Spring boot app

```
package com.access6;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DbConnect2Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DbConnect2Application.class, args);
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:vinanth
```

Comment: In `stdin.save(std);` std is not initialized and will be `null`

Comment: do i have to initialize std to null

Comment: You have to create an object of `Student`, populate the values and then save

Comment: can you elaborate please, I'm a beginner.

Comment: `Student std = new Student() ; std.setId(id); std.setName(name); std.setLocation(location);` add this to addStd() method . Then call `stdin.save(std);` .

Comment: i have created student object, but cannot call 'std.setId(id);' methods.after creating student method i'm getting new error 'could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.STUDENT(ID) [0, NULL, NULL]"; SQL statement: insert into student (location, name, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement'

Comment: 1. Verify the values you are setting to the Student object . 2. Verify the `StudentInt` repository individually and learn how to save an entity to db .3. Learn to debug the code

Comment: thanks for suggestions. it helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find the below code.

```
@RequestMapping("/addStd")
public ModelAndView addStd(@RequestParam ("id") String id, @RequestParam ("name") String name, 
@RequestParam ("location") String location,ModelMap mp ) {

  std = new Student() ;
  std.setId(id);
  std.setName(name);
  std.setLocation(location);

  mp.put("id", id);
  mp.put("name", name);
  mp.put("location", location);
  stdin.save(std);
return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

OR

Use modelAttribute to set request params into dto automatically,and here request parameter name and variable name from dto should be same.

```
@RequestMapping("/addStd")
public ModelAndView addStd(@ModelAttribute Student std,ModelMap mp ) {

  mp.put("id", std.getId());
  mp.put("name", std.getName());
  mp.put("location", std.getLocation());
  stdin.save(std);
return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

Comment: this is working, thanks !, although it is working fine i cannot connect to database. could you help me with it.

Comment: sorry,I never used h2 db, I am using mysql in my proj.

Comment: working fine with mysql but, i cannot connect h2. thanks for the suggestion you saved my day